# Using TRANSIENT grails GORM hibernate objects

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

What I'd like to do in my grails app is to create a lot of transient objects, and when the time is right... IF the time is right, then I would persist all the objects. In some cases, the time is never right, so they'd be thrown away and garbage collected.

But if I write some code like this:

```
    CollectingEvent collectingEvent = new CollectingEvent()
    CollectionUnit collectionUnit = new CollectionUnit()

    collectionUnit.collectingEvent = collectingEvent
    collectingEvent.collectionUnits.add(collectionUnit)
```

then I'll get a java.lang.NullPointerException because collectionUnits isn't initialized to a valid collection.

It's not clear if I should try and initialize it in the CollectingEvent object, or indeed what syntax I would use if I wanted to do that:

```
class CollectingEvent {
    static hasMany = [collectionUnits: CollectionUnit]
}
```

Is what I am trying to do something I ought to be doing in the GORM / hibernate library? Or am I going to have to store all my data somewhere else and only populate GORM objects when I'm sure I want it persisted?

Answer (score 0):

The transient problem has nothing to do with ne `NullPointerException`.

Please, try to explain in detail what you mean by transient and why the usual `new CollectionEvent()` and not saving this Object doen't work.

**The NullPointer**:

GORM uses Hibernate under the hood, but it puts an [active record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern) layer ontop of it.

Therefore, you should use the [addTo*](https://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/addTo.html) methods when you want to add a [Domain Class](https://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/Usage.html) to collection of another domain class. Like adding a `CollectionUnit` to a `CollectionEvent`.

You code should look like this:

```
    CollectingEvent collectingEvent = new CollectingEvent()
    CollectionUnit collectionUnit = new CollectionUnit()

    collectingEvent.addToCollectionUnits(collectionUnit)
```

Furthermore, your `CollectionUnit` class should declare that it belongs to the `CollectionUnit`. I guess, that the lifecycle of the `CollectionUnit` depends on the `CollectionEvent`, doesn't it?

```
 static belongsTo = [collectingEvent: CollectingEvent]
```

Comment: Transient means an object not persisted, and may not ever be persisted.

Comment: Using addToCollectionUnits seems to fix my issue. Thanks!

Comment: @xpusostomos : Does the "don't call `save()` on domain class instance" approach work for you to solve the "transient problem" ? If not, could you describe why it doesn't?